# Swift: Custom Encoder/Decoder fails to decode array, found string instead of an array

Tags: swift, codable

Because of `[AnyHashable: Any]` (I need it) I have to implement `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`. But when I run it it fails to decode the property with array value:

> typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

This is the code you can run in Playground:

```
struct ServerResponse: Codable {
    var headers: [AnyHashable: Any]?
    var items: [Item]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items, headers
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ServerResponse.CodingKeys.self)
        items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: ServerResponse.CodingKeys.items)
        let singleValueContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let stringDictionary = try singleValueContainer.decode([String: String].self)
        headers = [:]
        for (key, value) in stringDictionary {
            headers?[key] = value
        } 
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let stringDictionary: [String: String] = Dictionary(
            uniqueKeysWithValues: headers?.map {("\($0)", "\($1)")} ?? []
        )
        var singleValueContainer = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try singleValueContainer.encode(stringDictionary)
        
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: ServerResponse.CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(items, forKey: ServerResponse.CodingKeys.items)
    }

    struct Item: Codable {
        let name: String
    }
}

let testData = """
    {
        "items": [
                    {"name": "John"},
                    {"name": "Duo"}
                ]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(ServerResponse.self, from: testData)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

What is wrong with it? Why does it complain about getting `String` while I have put an array?
If I remove headers from the struct and conform to `Codable` everything works fine.

Comment: Your single-value container wraps `{ "items": [ ... ] }`, and you attempt to decode it as a `[String: String]` — but the value for the `items` key is an array and not a `String`. Can you confirm that commenting out the lines past `items = try container...` causes the error to not be thrown? (If so, there are still ways to decode the header items you're looking for.)

Comment: The problem is not the headers, if the data for headers exist it will work, the problem is items.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Yes commenting out that lines will fix the error

Comment: Unrelated but why do you convert *strong typed* `[String:String]` to *weak typed* `[AnyHashable: Any]`?

Comment: It's coming from another protocol I have to conform to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here lies in how you are attempting to extract items from this top-level dictionary, by attempting to decode it *as* a dictionary. Specifically,

```swift
let singleValueContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
let stringDictionary = try singleValueContainer.decode([String: String].self)
```

is the problematic snippet. With your particular JSON payload, `singleValueContainer` here wraps up

```
{
    "items": [ ... ],
    "..." // <- assuming there are other actual keys and values
}
```

This is valid to do, but when you attempt to decode the contents of the container as `[String: String]`, you are *asserting* that you expect the container to contain specifically a dictionary with `String` keys and `String` values; the value for the `items` key, however, is *not* a string, but an array.

When you have a collection with arbitrary values, the correct approach to extracting its contents is to use a keyed container instead. Specifically, you can use a keyed container whose key type can take on *any* `String` or `Int` value, as such:

```swift
struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let intValue: Int?
    let stringValue: String

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    }

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        intValue = Int(stringValue)
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }
}
```

With this coding key type, you can then request `decoder` as another keyed container — and this time, the keys can be arbitrary:

```swift
let untypedContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
```

The trick is that now, the *values* in `untypedContainer` are not asserted to be of any type until you try to decode them. You can then iterate over `untypedContainer.allKeys` (same as you iterate over `stringDictionary` at the moment), and for each key, you can decide how you want to `decode(_:forKey:)` out of the container. You could:

1. Attempt to decode a `String`, and if you get a `DecodinerError.typeMismatch` error, just skip the key-value pair
2. Inspect the value of each key, and if you have *known* keys (or keys which match some pattern, or similar) you're looking for, decode only those instead

For example:

```swift
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ServerResponse.CodingKeys.self)
    items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: ServerResponse.CodingKeys.items)

    headers = [:]
    let untypedContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
    for key in untypedContainer.allKeys {
        do {
            let value = try untypedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: key)
            headers[key.stringValue] = value
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch { /* skip this key-value pair */ }
    }
}
```